# Firebrreath plugin crash using DestroyWindow

Tags: c++, boost, window, firebreath

I need a method for destroying my window in firebreath but when i use DestroyWindow() the plugin crashes and CloseWindow() is not a viable option for me. I use the gInstance for making my window as otherwise the window dosn't update. So I guess there are two options for this error/crash, either using another method for destrying the window or another method for construction the window.

here is my call

```
CalibrationScreen(gInstance, NULL, (LPSTR)"test", SW_SHOW);
```

here is the function

```
int WINAPI TobiiWrapper::CalibrationScreen(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc;
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = lpCmdLine;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
{
    return 0;
}

full_screen_window = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_TOPMOST,
    lpCmdLine,
    (LPCSTR)"Tobii Calibration Screen",
    WS_POPUP,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    _screenWidth, _screenHeight,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if(full_screen_window == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(full_screen_window, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(full_screen_window);
GdiSetBatchLimit(1);

PAINTSTRUCT  ps;
hdc = BeginPaint(full_screen_window, &ps);
startNextOrFinish(); //run through target loop
EndPaint(full_screen_window, &ps);
CloseWindow(full_screen_window);
DestroyWindow(full_screen_window);

return 0;
}
```

The WndProc if you need it

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(msg)
{
    case WM_PAINT:
        return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
    case WM_QUIT:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_CHAR:  
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused; so you're creating your own window but then destroying it later?  Is this on the main thread or a seperate thread? What is the crash stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: Sorry I'm also confused. 
But yes! im creating my own window using the hInstance (called gInstance) from the BlankFactories.cpp. Im not creating or using any thread for the window, as I count make it work. See below:
//boost::thread* thr = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&TobiiWrapper::CalibrationScreen, this, gInstance, NULL, (LPSTR)"test", SW_SHOW));
CalibrationScreen(gInstance, NULL, (LPSTR)"test", SW_SHOW);

Comment: Take a look at the WinMessageThread object in the FireBreath codebase; it has an example of creating a window that doesn't crash. (it's a messaging window, but should be similar)

Comment: Sorry, but where do i find that?

Comment: sorry, I mistyped the name.  src/PluginCore/Win/WinMessageWindow.cpp